# Can someone please explain `List<BaseType>`

Tags: dart, operators

In the [Dart cheatsheet](https://dart.dev/codelabs/dart-cheatsheet#null-aware-operators) to null-aware-operators it says:

> Specifying types is handy when you initialize a list with contents of a subtype, but still want the list to be `List<BaseType>`:
>
> `final aListOfBaseType = <BaseType>[SubType(), SubType()];`

Could someone please elaborate on this?

Comment: Could you update your question so "but still want the list to be List" are written as "but still want the list to be List<BaseType>". It seems like Stackoverflow has eaten the lart part. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see this in the following example (output is from DartPad):

```
class BaseType {}

class SubType extends BaseType {}

void main() {
  final aList = [SubType(), SubType()];
  print(aList.runtimeType); // JSArray<SubType>

  aList.add(BaseType()); // error: The constructor returns type 'BaseType' that isn't of expected type 'SubType'.

  final aListOfBaseType = <BaseType>[SubType(), SubType()];
  print(aListOfBaseType.runtimeType); // JSArray<BaseType>

  aListOfBaseType.add(BaseType()); // works
}
```

So if you don't specify any generic type for the list, Dart will try to automatically guess the type. So if the list are initialized with only `SubType` objects the type of the List will be `List<SubType>`.

Since the list are defined as `List<SubType>`, you will not be able to add any `BaseType` objects to the list. So if you instead want the list to be defined as `List<BaseType>`, you will need to define that when you create the list object.

Comment: maybe a bit late but thank you nevertheless! :)